# Haskell uniq -c emulator code explanation

Tags: haskell

This code seems a bit obtuse to me... Anyone care to help me out by explaining it?

```
uniq_c l = [ nl (tam l) i s | (s,i) <- uniq_c' l]

tam = maximum . map snd . uniq_c'

uniq_c' [] = []
uniq_c' (h:t) = let (list,rest) = span (==h) t
                    n = length list + 1
                in (h,n) : uniq_c' rest

nl tam n line = let l = length $ show n
                    l_tam = length $ show tam
                    n' = replicate (l_tam-l) " "
                in concat n' ++ show n ++ " " ++ line
```

Comment: That code is terrible, try to avoid picking up any habits from it.

Comment: I thought it looked a little suspect. Care to explain why?

Comment: I'll post a reply with better code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uniq_c` provides a count of the number of times a string occurs in a list of strings concatenated with a space to the particular string:

```
*A> uniq_c ["The","quick","brown","fox","fox"]
["1 The","1 quick","1 brown","2 fox"]

*A> uniq_c $ ["The","quick","brown","fox","fox","fox"] ++ (replicate 100 "fox")
["  1 The","  1 quick","  1 brown","103 fox"]
```

`uniq_c'` provides a list of tuples of `(string,count)`.

`tam` finds the largest count (which will be the last occurrence for any particular string).

`nl` indents the counts so that the counts are right justified.

```
*A> mapM_ putStrLn $ uniq_c $ ["The","quick","brown","fox","fox","fox"] ++ (replicate 100 "fox")
  1 The
  1 quick
  1 brown
103 fox
```

Comment: Note that this is run-length encoding: `uniq_c ["a","b","a"] == ["1 a","1 b","1 a"]`.

Answer (score 6):

That code isn't very good.  It doesn't reuse any of the existing Haskell libraries.
Here is an alternative.  The `group` function does the meat of the work; recognizing repeated occurrences.  The the `length &&& head` takes each such sublist and makes a count and the word.  Finally `uniq_c` finds the maximum width and uses `printf` to format the output.

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.List
import Text.Printf

uniq :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
uniq = map (length &&& head) . group

uniq_c :: [String] -> [String]
uniq_c l =
    let us = uniq l
        width = length . show . maximum . map fst $ us
    in  map (uncurry $ printf "%*d %s" width) us
```